# Error occurs while running Eclipse Emulator

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova, android-emulator

Iam Beginer for Eclipse Phonegap,when i try to create a small app,Emulator always shows a error message as "

```
Failed to install Homeapp.apk on device 'emulator-5554': timeout
 Launch canceled
```

!",Why it happens all time,Suggest a solution for this error.

Comment: Try to reset your emulator or IDE. I had this problems when adb process has some issue

Comment: just restart both your eclipse and emulator and run again :) it will be fine dude don't panic

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this :

```
Go to Window --> Preferences --> Click on Android Arrow --> DDMS and change ADB Connection Timeout value to some large value then current.
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

It happened to me so many times because the emulator stays unused for a long time and adb stops responding that is why the emulator timeout occurs.

**The one solution** for this is to close the emulator and restart it again.

**The other is**

Try changing the ADB connection timeout. I think it defaults that to **5000ms** and  changed to **10000ms** to get rid of that problem.

If you are in Eclipse, you can do this by going through

```
 Window -> Preferences -> Android -> DDMS -> ADB Connection Timeout (ms)
```

Comment: Ghare kyare javanu 6?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Eclipse the Just restart your emulator....hope you will not get Time out error again...